# Why shadowColor: '...' - is not applied for drawer styles on Android of “react-native-drawer” component?

Tags: react-native

May be someone know why "shadowColor" property is not applied for drawer styles on Android? (With iOS looks like everything ok)

### Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots

```
<Drawer
 type="overlay"
 ...
 styles={{
  drawer: {shadowColor: 'black', shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 2}
   ...
 }}   
>
```

[image: Screenshot]

### Environment

react-native-drawer version: 2.3.0

React Native version: 0.41.2

Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android

Device info
Simulator/Device? - Simulator Android 4.1 (API16), Simulator Android 7.1.1 (API25)

OS version? - MacOS 10.12.3

Debug/Release? - Debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shadow` will only work on ios. You can try `elevation` instead which is only available to android also.

shadow props:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html

check out elevation in View component:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.41/docs/view.html#style

Comment: "shadow will only work on ios" thanks, after your answer I have found this in [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.41/docs/shadow-props.html) :)

Comment: Also I knew about "elevation" but unfortunately I cannot apply it on my Android 5.1.1 although in documentation is written "Only supported on Android 5.0+".

Comment: ...I put "elevation" into "<ListView style={..." (ListView is main component which represent "<Drawer content={<MainMenu />}..."), into "<Drawer styles={{ drawer: { ..." and then even wrap ListView into View with "elevation" prop in styles but in all these cases I do not see any shadow in Android. May be someone know what the reason can be?

Comment: @Stich
I couldnt test right now but have you tried putting the elevation in contentContainerStyle instead?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use package like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow. haven't tried it though.

Comment: @Stich Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem was that I used a small value of elevation. For some reason there is no "shadow" with "elevation: 5" but "elevation: 20"  fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Stich Great! kindly mark my answer as correct if it solved the problem. For others to see

Comment: with pleasure, once I have enough reputation for this action :)